# Maximum number of characters allowed per tag in the jQuery UI plugin Tag-it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tag-it

Using the jQuery UI plugin [Tag-it](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it), it is possible to enter tags with 100s of characters such as:

"loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitseddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliquautenimadminimveniamquisnostrudexercitationullamco"

I'm trying to set a maximum number of characters allowed per tag. So far I have tried `tagLimit` but this limits the total number of tags allowed but not the character limit for each tag.

Does anyone know how I could set a limit to the number of characters allowed per tag?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tags").tagit({
        tagLimit: 5,
        allowSpaces: true,
        placeholderText: 'Tags'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you kingkero, for the edit

Comment: You are welcome. But I am afraid I cannot help you.. Also I believe you have to edit `tag-it.js` to implement this feature yourself - or use another plugin for tags

Comment: I thought editing tag-it.js might be needed. I'd prefer not to use another plugin because tag-it offers some features which I really like. Hoping somebody can help.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the best solution, but I edited the _cleanedInput method to cut each tag to 100 characters at max (in my application I doubt there would be any tag exceeding 100 characters, not even close to 50!).

In the plugin, I changed this:

```
_cleanedInput: function() {
    return $.trim(this.tagInput.val().replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1'));
},
```

To:

```
_cleanedInput : function() {
    return $.trim(this.tagInput.val().replace(/^"(.*)"$/, "$1")).substr(0, 100);
},
```